# Jquery compare function doesn't work on integers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am trying to arrange my array by the last 4 substrings, which are numbers and it's not working correctly.
the code is

```
function sortArray(){
    top10.sort(function(a, b){
        var ax = a.substr(6, 4);
        var bx = b.substr(6, 4);
        return bx>ax;
        console.log(top10);
    });
}

top10 = [];
$.get('user_db_hm.txt', function(myContentFile)
        {
            top10 = myContentFile.split("\n");
            sortArray();
        }, 'text');
```

the console.log is

["dupes - 9
", "zombi - 8
", "rofls - 7
", "kombi - 6
", "abcdf - 5", "johny - 4
", "kolio - 22
", "gosho - 2
", "rapis - 14
", "pesho - 1
"]

Comment: How you can get output in console when calling `console.log` after `return` statement?

Comment: Are the contents of `top10` after you split them the same as what you show above? If so, when I log ax and bx I get values like `- 8 ` and `- 6 `

Comment: i called the array in the console,i also can see the result because i'm putting the array in divs.

Comment: Strings are not numbers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eppq92cx/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the new sorted array produced by `sort()` and make sure the substrings are converted to numbers, so you can compare them correctly.

Try this:

```
function sortArray(){
    return top10.sort(function(a, b){
        var ax = Number(a.substr(7, 4));
        var bx = Number(b.substr(7, 4));
        return bx>ax;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your program,

1. As @A. Wolff has said you need to use `parseInt` for converting string to Intger
2. Second the `substr` returns data as `- 22` which is not what you want

So, Try this

```
top10.sort(function(a, b){
        var ax = a.substr(7, 4);
        var bx = b.substr(7, 4);
        ax.trim();
        bx.trim();
        return parseInt(bx)>parseInt(ax);
    });
console.log(top10);
```

### And , here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7x5mftr/)

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vuvare/1/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```
function strNum(v){ return +v.match(/\d+/)||''; }

function sortArray( arr ){
  arr.sort(function(a, b){
    var ax = strNum(a);
    var bx = strNum(b);
    return bx>ax;
  });
  console.log(arr);
}


$.get("user_db_hm.txt", function( data ){
  sortArray( data.split("\n") );
}, "text");
```

logs:

> ["kolio - 22", "rapis - 14", "dupes - 9", "zombi - 8", "rofls - 7", "kombi - 6", "abcdf - 5", "johny - 4", "gosho - 2", "pesho - 1"]